# "Undefined property: stdClass::$email" laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http

Meu validator retorna os erros existentes na requisição.

Gostaria de verificar se na variável que eu guardo meus erros possui o erro email para então retornar o response correto.

Tentei algo como:

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $errors = $this->validator($request->all())->errors();

        if(count($errors))
        {
            $obj = json_decode($errors);
            if($obj->email){
                return response(['errors' => 'Este email já está cadastrado no sistema, tente outro.'], 401);
            }else{
                return response(['errors' => $errors],401);
            }
        }

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        return response(['mensagem' => "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!"]);
    }
```

Porém, recebo:

> message: "Undefined property: stdClass::$email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A forma correta de verificar se houve um erro na validação do e-mail é utilizar a função `has`:

```
if ($errors->has('email')) {
    // Código de tratamento
}
```

Você não precisa usar `json_decode` porque a variável `$errors` não está em formato Json.

Eu sugiro que você leia a documentação sobre [lidar com erros na validação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#working-with-error-messages) caso queira manipular melhor os erros.

E se você estiver usando esse método apenas para retornar uma mensagem em português, eu sugiro que leia [isso](https://blog.especializati.com.br/traduzir-laravel/) para aprender como adicionar tradução as mensagens de erro de validação.